# Samsung Galaxy s10e requires password every few days, is it possible to disable safely?

Tags: security, encryption, password, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Galaxy s10e, protected by a *very* long password and fingerprints.
I specifically went for a very long password intending to only type it in after restarting the phone.

In fact, the phone requires entering the password every 2 ish days, which, I read, is a [standard practice with Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/196043/18039).

However, in the security settings I was able to find "Other security settings - Strong protection" that reads:

> Encrypt your phone using your secure lock type
>
> After restarting, you'll need to unlock your phone using your pattern, PIN, or password to access features other than calls, messages, and alarms.

That setting is on, and I believe it is this one that requires the password every so often. And it would appear from its wording that if I disable it, the phone will be unencrypted.

- Am I correct in that assumption? **Will disabling that setting make the phone unencrypted?** (I don't want that.)
- Is there a way to **disable asking for the password every so often** with Galaxy s10 specifically (as opposed to stock Android) **without compromising the device encryption**?

At the moment it feels like this feature works to weaken the phone's protection, not strengthen it. By asking for a password every so often, it pushes me to go for simpler passwords that are easier to type in.